# State space and latent space instability

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Reinforcement learning assumes an MDP with an a priori state space representation. Assume the state space is the raw images from a game, and we use convNets or another method to generate s latent state space. If we built the latent space first, we could run our RL algorithms on the fixed latent space representation, but what if we switched between learning a policy or value function on the latent state space, and also updating the latent space generator itself? Is there any theory or research on how to make such a system work?

Comment: See [Embed to Control](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5964-embed-to-control-a-locally-linear-latent-dynamics-model-for-control-from-raw-images), a paper which learns a latent space and dynamics model which is locally linear, allowing for arbitrary control algorithms to operate in this space.